# How to delete a file which is made by using file creation operations in php in a particular path?

Tags: php

I have created code to create file automatically in a particular path folder. I wanted to delete that file using php code. I have used the function

```
unlink("../game_page/$fname.php");
```

here the filename is stored in the variable $fname and it is a php file. But this code is not working. Can anyone say how to delete that particular file in that path?

Comment: "Not working" is not a helpful comment. What _is_ it doing / showing? Have you checked errors logs? etc etc.

Comment: First change to unlink("../game_page/".$fname.".php");

Comment: Then your path or your filename is wrong.

@RaghavRangani That doesn't help now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] after you folder path.

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/game_page/".$fname.".php");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 unlink("../game_page/".$fname.".php");
```

Also check the permission if that user has to delete that file and set by using chmod

Comment: does $fname has a valid file name that exixts?